# Как вызвать метод в активити из фрагмента?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-manager

Немогу перезагрузить WebView который находится в Фрагменте я вызывааю его в mainactivity

так пытаюсь его вызвать в активити

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_progress_show) {
            progress_menu_item.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_layout);

   //Так я его призываю
            TwoFragment  fragment = new TwoFragment();
       fragment. Refress();





   return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

а это метод во фрагменте

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        final PullRefreshLayout layout = (PullRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

        layout.setEnabled(false);




        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://premiumdental.az/wp-content/uploads/vtour/tour.html");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //metodi optimizacii


        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
            mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
            mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

        }
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);




        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


        return v;

//пытаюсь перезагрузить его при нажатии в актити
  }
    public void Refress(){
        mWebView.reload();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы создаёте новый фрагмент, он не находится в активити, его нет на экране и у него нет разметки.

Вам надо получить уже отображаемый фрагмент, который прикреплён к активити.

Судя по вашим предыдущим вопросам, фрагменты у вас во ViewPager отображаются через адаптер. Вот именно из адаптера и получите ссылку на ваш фрагмент и у него вызывайте метод